# Rearranging tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two groups of tiles as shown in the graphic below. Each tile is a DIV.

[image]

I want to be able to drag a tile to a new position within a group or to a new position within the adjacent group.

And similar to windows 8, I also want to be able to drag a tile in a group to the space between two groups to create a new group for the tile.

[image]

Here is how far I was able to get - I was able to create a single group that is drag-sortable.

```
<div class="demo">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default wide">3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/psivadasan/FmWCx/

Appreciate any help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similiar in the past, this is how I achieved it: http://jsfiddle.net/dazefs/vGYVX/

```
<div style="background-color:Gray">

<ul id="sortable">
    <li>
      <span style="background-color:yellow">
         Item 1
       </span>

     </li>
    <li>
     <span style="background-color:red">
       Item 2
     </span>

    </li>
    <li>
      <span style="background-color:green">
     Item 3
     </span>

  </li>
    <li>
    <span style="background-color:Blue">
           Item 4
     </span>
     </li>
   </ul>

<ul id="sortable2" style="width:60%">
<li>
    <span style="background-color:yellow">
        Item 5
    </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <span style="background-color:red">
        Item 6
    </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <span style="background-color:green">
        Item 7
    </span>
   </li>
    <li>
       <span style="background-color:Blue">
          Item 8
       </span>
   </li>
</ul>

 </div>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable2, #sortable",
        receive: function (event, ui) {
             alert('item has been sorted');
         }
    });

    //})
});
```

**To achieve with 3 tile groups:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dazefs/XRdz6/

Comment: Thanks Darren. Would you know how to create a new group by dragging it to the space between two tile groups?

Comment: You would have to have a new ul tag.  (3 in total). left list, center ul, right ul and then just call $("#newul").sortable() or $("#sortable, #sortable2 #sortable3").sortable( ....... from my code

Comment: Hi Darren, can you help me with this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745140/rearrange-tiles-within-an-area

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/A8NYw/

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1,#sortable2")
        .sortable({ connectWith: ".sortable"})
        .disableSelection();
});​
```