# Rearrange tiles within an area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, tiles

I'm trying to create a tile grid that can be rearranged. The tiles are of different sizes. Here's how far I've gotten.

http://jsfiddle.net/psivadasan/dMtRs/

How do I prevent tiles from being rearranged outside the grey area? I don't want this to happen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYB0V.png

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Look at the dimensions of the element and don't allow it to be dropped if its neighbour is the wrong type.

Comment: I want tiles to rearrange within the grey container. When rearranging, I don't want a tile to go out of the container.

Comment: I tried something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dMtRs/8/ . I think I failed, but maybe someone can pick that up. Good night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `containment` option: This will stop the elements being dragged outside.

```
$('ul').sortable( "option", "containment", 'parent' );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dazefs/dMtRs/7/

Comment: Hi Darren, Thanks for taking the time. When I rearrange the tiles(move 5 up, for example), another tile still goes outside the container.

Comment: @b-marls - If I might ask - did this really answer your question?